# Layering in CSS theorycraft

Tags: html, css

So if you're aware of layers in photoshop, its basically like the top down look onto a photo, and you can bring certain parts of layers to the front or back and rearrange them etc.

I'm having trouble replicating this concept with HTML/CSS.
Essentially, what I want to do is to have:
1) background image (bottom most layer)

```
    html { 
      background-image: url('website.com/pic.jpg');
      background: no-repeat center fixed cover;
    }
```

2) black opaque rectangle covering background image (penultimate)

```
    body { 
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      background-size: cover;

    }
```

3) content/text (top layer)

```
    .content { }
```

not sure what the rest of the CSS needs to be to make this layering effect work. the height of  is 0 all the time and adding height: 100%; doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `z-index` and `position`

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code so that we can help?

Answer (score 0):

You need three things:

- Change the `display` property of the image from `inline-block` to `block`
- Change the `position` property of the image and the layers from `relative` to `absolute`
- Specify the stack order (`z-index`) property of the layers and the image. element with the lowest `z-index` value will be placed at the bottom, and that with the highest value will be placed on top of the others.

Comment: how do i fix the fact that height of <body> tag and <html> tag is 0 and i can't make it bigger

Comment: Try `body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: it says in my first post that setting those attributes doesn't do anything.